# react-diagrams DefaultPortModel color

Tags: javascript, reactjs, diagram

How to modify the color of a port (`DefaultPortModel`) in react-diagrams please ? I did not found a way to do that.

I want to be able customize the color of:

- The port line (the full rectangle containing text `vidout-rtsp`)
- The hover box (the yellow/green one)
- The same box when not hover

[image: Port hover color]

Here is a part of my code:

```js
class NoDuplicateInputPortModel extends DefaultPortModel {
  noDuplicateInput(port) {
    return !port.getOptions().in || Object.keys(port.getLinks()).length === (port === this ? 1 : 0);
  }
  canLinkToPort(port) {
    return super.canLinkToPort(port) && this.noDuplicateInput(this) && this.noDuplicateInput(port);
  }
}


class CamPortModel extends NoDuplicateInputPortModel {
  constructor(isIn, name, label) {
    super(isIn, name, label);
    this.color = 'rgba(255,255,0,1)';
  }


// Some hidded lines...

for(let camera_info of module.template.cameras_info) {
  let camPort = node.addPort(new CamPortModel(true, `cam-${camera_info.name}`, `cam-${camera_info.name}`));
  modules_camera_ports[module.id][camera_info.id] = camPort
  camPort.getOptions().id =  `mod-${module.id}-camport-${camera_info.id}`;
}
```

Comment: Did you find ? Maybe modifying css ?

Comment: I didn't found, I finaly used a text prefix to differenciate port types.
Maybe it can be done with css, but I'm not a web dev and neither a front dev, I lost a lot of time when trying to do this things..